Screen detection Ubuntu 24.04 (Login)
After an update, my Ubuntu 24.04 could no longer recognize the parameters of the screen. I was able to solve the problem by deleting the .config/monitors.xml file in my user directory.It was automatically re-created the next time I loged in.
Unfortunately, this does not apply to the login dialog.
My question is: Where is the monitor configured for the login dialog?
